# Nativescript RadAutoCompleteTextView's token not showing image from local path

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I want to show image in token from a local path,

which looks like this (`ProfileImageLocalPath`):  `"/data/data/com.nativescript.app/files/app/audit/b25b1229-3100-4b32-a381-8ca506d58d00_b25b1229-3100-4b32-a381-8ca506d58d00.png"`

my initDataItems() looks like below

```
private initDataItems() {
 this._items = new ObservableArray<tokenmodel>();

 for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
   this._items.push(new UserModel(this.users[i], i, this.users[i].DisplayName, 
   this.users[i].ProfileImageLocalPath));
 }
}
```

I have extended token model as below:

```
export class UserModel extends TokenModel {
    public Item: any;
    public ItemIndex: any;
    public Text: string;
    constructor(Item: any, ItemIndex: any, Text: string, image: string) {
        super(Text, image);
        this.Item = Item;
        this.ItemIndex = ItemIndex;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.Item.ItemId;
    }
}
```

But my token is not showing any images.

It only shows image if I use the image resource path : `"res://some_image"`

Any idea? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Manoj I am unable to provide playground example, how can i provide data in phone storage in playground example?

Comment: The data on phone is written at some point. You could download a image, write it to storage upon launch, use the image on TokenModel to simulate the issue.